# Title: CirrusWrapper ERROR: turn discovery peer configuration error - Error: read ECONNRESET

Tags: javascript, kubernetes, twilio, twilio-api, turn

I'm encountering an error while configuring TURN server discovery in my yaml file. The specific error message I'm receiving is "CirrusWrapper ERROR: turn discovery peer configuration error - Error: read ECONNRESET". I'm unsure how to resolve this issue. Could someone please provide guidance or suggestions on troubleshooting steps?

I would appreciate any insights, troubleshooting steps, or suggestions for resolving this issue.
I need to ingrate Twilio with existing pixel-streaming setup

Here is my Yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: unrealengine
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: poc-on-eks
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.0.1
    app: stream
  name: stream
  namespace: poc
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: unrealengine
      app.kubernetes.io/part-of: poc-on-eks
      app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.0.1
      app: stream
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/port: "9000"
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        prometheus.io/path: "/metrics"
        sidecar.istio.io/rewriteAppHTTPProbers: "true"
      labels:
        app: stream
        app.kubernetes.io/component: unrealengine
        app.kubernetes.io/name: stream
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: poc-on-eks
        app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.0.1
        version: 0.0.1
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: app.pixel/streamer
                operator: Exists
      containers:
      - args:
        - --configFile=/config/cirrus.json
        - --httpPort=3000
        - --streamerPort=8888
        - --UseMatchmaker=true
        - --MatchmakerAddress=matchmaker
        - --MatchmakerPort=9999
        - --useMatchmaker=true
        - --matchmakerAddress=matchmaker
        - --matchmakerPort=9999
        - --ueRestEndpoint=http://localhost:8111
        - --rtcConfigSvc=http://global.turn.twilio.com:3478?transport=udp
        #- --rtcConfigSvc=http://turn-discovery:3000
        - --metricsPort=9000
        env:
        - name: POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: EXTRA_PEERCONNECTION_OPTIONS
          value: >-
            --peerConnectionOptions={
              "iceServers":[
                {
                  "urls": ["stun:global.stun.twilio.com:3478","turn:global.turn.twilio.com:443?transport=tcp"],
                  "username": "<Username>",
                  "credential": "<password>"
                }
              ]
            }
        - name: TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID
          value: <TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID>
        - name: TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
          value: <TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN>
        image: ghcr.io/oracle-quickstart/oke-unreal-pixel-streaming/signalserver:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        #livenessProbe:
         # httpGet:
          #  path: /
           # port: http
        name: signaler
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
          name: http
        - containerPort: 8888
          name: stream
        - containerPort: 9000
          name: metrics
        #readinessProbe:
         # httpGet:
          #  path: /
           # port: http
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /config
          name: config
      - env:
        - name: SIGNAL_URL
          value: ws://localhost:8888
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: pixel-stream-configs
        image: ghcr.io/stevensu1977/ue4-pixelstreaming/actionrpg-project:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: streamer
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8111
          name: rest
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
      - args:
        - -ec
        - |
          while true; do
            # obtain player connections from metrics
            export PLAYERS=$(curl -s "${SELF_METRICS}" | grep ^signalserver_player_socket_connections | awk '{print $2}')

            # apply player connections as the pod deletion cost
            kubectl annotate pod "${POD_NAME}" \
              --namespace "${NAMESPACE}" \
              --overwrite controller.kubernetes.io/pod-deletion-cost="${PLAYERS}" || true
            sleep 10
          done
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        env:
        - name: SELF_METRICS
          value: http://localhost:9000/custom
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        image: ghcr.io/oracle-quickstart/oke-unreal-pixel-streaming/kubetools:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: annotation-agent
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 5m
      serviceAccountName: stream-svc-account
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      tolerations:
      - key: "app.pixel/streamer"
        operator: "Exists"
        effect: "NoExecute"
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          name: pixel-app-configs
        name: config
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: stream-discovery
    app.kubernetes.io/component: unrealengine
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: poc-on-eks
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.0.1
  name: stream-discovery
  namespace: poc
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app: stream
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  EXTRA_ARGS: -RestApiPort=8111 -AllowPixelStreamingCommands -PixelStreamingHideCursor
    -PixelStreamingWebRTCMaxFps=30 -PixelStreamingWebRTCDisableReceiveAudio -FullStdOutLogOutput
  RES_X: "1920"
  RES_Y: "1080"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: unrealengine
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: poc-on-eks
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.0.1
  name: pixel-stream-configs
  namespace: poc
```